# User Authentation using php and mysql

Tags: php, android, mysql

guys i am working on android 2.2 i am stuck where the user need to be authenticated with his use name and password

below is my code

PHP code:

```
<?php
$un=$_POST['userid'];
$pw=$_POST['password'];

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("myhealthcare");

$sql=mysql_query("select userid,password from register where userid='$un' and password='$pw'");

while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))

$output[]=$row;

print(json_encode($output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Java Code:

```
ArrayList<NameValuePair> nvp = new  ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

             nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("userid", userid.getText().toString()));
             nvp.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password.getText().toString()));
             String un = userid.getText().toString();
             String pass = password.getText().toString();

             System.out.println("user name is " + un);
             System.out.println("password is " +pass);
//           Log.e(""+sid.getText().toString(),"0"); 
//           Log.e(""+sname.getText().toString(),"0");
                try {
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/login.php");
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nvp));
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                is = entity.getContent();
                } catch(Exception e){
                    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
                }
                try {
                    BufferedReader bf  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
                    sb = new StringBuilder();
                    sb.append(bf.readLine()+ "\n");
                    String line="0";
                       while ((line = bf.readLine()) != null) {
                                      sb.append(line + "\n");
                        }
                        is.close();
                        result=sb.toString();
                    System.out.println("value of result " +result);

                }catch(Exception e){
                      Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
                }
                String unm,pwd;
                try {

                    jArray = new JSONArray(result);

                    JSONObject json_data = null;

                    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                         unm = json_data.getString("userid");
                         pwd = json_data.getString("password");

                         System.out.println("databse user name  is " +unm);
                         System.out.println("databse password is " +pwd);

                     }

                } catch(JSONException e1){
                      Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No details Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                  } catch (ParseException e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                }
```

i am able to fetch the value from database but i am not able to compare with user entered values please help

Comment: [Bobby Tables alert!](http://www.bobby-tables.com/) What if I set both my username and password to `' or '1' = '1`?

Comment: Shouldn't the authentication occur on the webserver, instead of passing the username and password back to the client? And have a look at `mysql_real_escape_string()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the PHP sometheing like this instead, to do the authentication on the server and not passing the login info back and forth:

```
<?php
$un=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['userid']);
$pw=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("myhealthcare");

$result=mysql_query("select userid from register where userid='$un' and password='$pw'");

if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
   print("Not authorized"); // Or send a json-encoded object containing the message
} else {
   print("Authorized");
}
mysql_close();
?>
```

**Update**

Use PHP's [mysql_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php) before running any data input by a user in your SQL. Otherwise you open your DB to [SQL-injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), which is really bad.

Comment: please tell what should i do in my .java file after editing my php code

Comment: @Goofy Not a Java-programmer so I can't give you an example, but to verify if the user login was right or not, you read the response from the server. If it returns "Not authorized" then the user credentials were incorrect and you do whaterever action you want to then. If it returns "Authorized", then the credentials were correct and your do whatever you want to do then.

Comment: hey i got to know what is mysql_real_escape_string does...how to send a send a json-encoded object from php and how to i get it in class show an error msg if its wrong.

Comment: Well how about looking in the PHP manual - I've already posted a link for mysql_real_escape_string. Here is [json_encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) as well - it is all there. As I said, can't help you with the Java-part.